# docker access to the requested resource is not authorized

Tags: docker

I have ubuntu 14 and have installed docker 1.8.3. Unfortunately I have this error:

```
sudo docker login
Username (mauriziobioinfo): 
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/maurizio/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded

sudo docker push   mauriziobioinfo/varscan
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/mauriziobioinfo/varscan] (len: 1)
ec3a068ba18d: Buffering to Disk 
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

Comment: Here is the answer http://askubuntu.com/a/688875/250747. You need to create a repository `varscan` first.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar error message using a repository on quay.io specifically.  I had to mark the image as public even after a `docker login quay.io` command.  It was an odd error and an odd solution since I had permissions to the image.

Comment: I'm also on Quay and I got this error. I could pull but not push. I found that the solution was to do `docker logout quay.io` before I logged in. That removes any existing read-only credentials you may have.

Answer (score 11):

The solution for me was to run "docker login" before the command.
So I logged in and then pushed.

Answer (score 6):

Things to troubleshoot:

1. `docker login` must be executed before a `docker push username/repository:tag` command.

   The `docker push` is not that automatic that it would give a different error message when not being logged in (or that it even would prompt for login on itself)
2. Double check your username in the push command line
3. Create the repository in the docker web-interface
4. Double check that the repository name in the push argument matches an existing one

   That means search for it under:

   ```
   https://hub.docker.com/u/$username/
   ```
5. Move an existing `/root/.docker/config.json` out of the way in case it is broken. Then, re-execute `docker login`.
6. Check the API URL in `/root/.docker/config.json`. For example, [with some docker versions (e.g. 1.8.1/1.9.1) you have to replace](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-not-working-in-1-8-1-not-logged-in/2894/17) `docker.io` with `https://index.docker.io/v1/`
7. If you execute some docker commands with `sudo` then make sure that all of them are executed with sudo (e.g. check if `alias docker` returns a definition)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have previously created this repository on the web interface of Docker Hub.

Make sure that the name of the image you're trying to push is identical with the name of the repository you have created.

Comment: I also had this problem while trying to run docker without sudo ( ie: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group) in docker 1.9.1 build 7206621.  Solution was to just use "sudo docker push" instead of "docker push".

Answer (score 0):

Docker login from terminal is required. Below is my terminal output showing before and after the login.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-50:~/dockertest$ docker push anuvrattiku/anuvrattiku-repository
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/anuvrattiku/anuvrattiku-repository]
3cd43b7ac945: Preparing 
5f70bf18a086: Preparing 
6f32b23ac95d: Preparing 
14d918629d81: Preparing 
fd0e26195ab2: Preparing 
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-50:~/dockertest$ docker push anuvrattiku/anuvrattiku-repository:1.0The push refers to a repository [docker.io/anuvrattiku/anuvrattiku-repository]
3cd43b7ac945: Preparing 
5f70bf18a086: Preparing 
6f32b23ac95d: Preparing 
14d918629d81: Preparing 
fd0e26195ab2: Preparing 
unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-50:~/dockertest$ docker login
Username: my_user_id
Password: 
Email: my_email_id
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-50:~/dockertest$ docker push anuvrattiku/anuvrattiku-repository:1.0The push refers to a repository [docker.io/anuvrattiku/anuvrattiku-repository]
3cd43b7ac945: Pushed 
5f70bf18a086: Pushed 
6f32b23ac95d: Pushed 
14d918629d81: Pushed 
fd0e26195ab2: Pushed 
1.0: digest: sha256:2436bcf56c15f50f51516204808bb4f5ab5f9d46c5e995435dcab528b06c3683 size: 5288
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-50:~/dockertest$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to use quay and you got this error thats probably because you need to use `docker login quay.io` command
You will have to create a password to use it.
Go to account settings and create a new CLI Password.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's relevant for someone:
I had a very similar problem with the local docker repo of my company.

- the docker login was successful
- credentials got automatically added to pass/gnupg
- but the docker pull didn't work and gave the error message `unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized`

Turned out the gnupg store was locked, but the query for the password did not get through to me.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error.
I hope this example helps someone.
Helped:

```
docker login nexus.example.com
```

input **username/password** from **nexus**.
Maybe you need to logout before doing this

```
docker logout
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).